# shell_exec returns NULL if I import theano in python script

Tags: php, python, theano

I use shell_exec() in php to execute a python script. However, when I import my own module in the script, shell_exec() returns NULL, here is the python script:

```
import theano
import sys

video_file_name = sys.argv[1]
print video_file_name
```

But when I don't import theano, shell_exec() works well. Here's my shell_exec() code:

```
$output = array();
$command = escapeshellcmd('python test.py Videos');
$output = shell_exec($command);
var_dump($output);
```

Is it because that import theano needs a long time that shell_exec() has some limitations that it can't wait that long?

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem, it's nothing to do with theano, it's actually a permission problem with apache, as usually. Here's how I solved it, in case this may help someone.
try this code in your python scirpt:

```
try:
    import theano
except Exception as e:
    print('Failed to open file: %s' % (e,))
```

Then I found it throws a permission error, after I use chmod to change the permission, everything works fine.